# (Re)Starting a Windows Service from out of my C# code does not work

Tags: c#, windows, service

To update my self-written **Windows Service**, I wrote a C# program that stops the service, copies the new DLLs and then restarts it.

My first approach was the following:

```cs
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
service.Stop();
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
// (...) copy the dll files
service.Start();
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
```

While stopping the service worked, the start method produced the following error:

```
Cannot start service FOVEA Service Debug on computer '.'.   
at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)    at
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
```

Running my update program as Administrator made no difference.

So I tried to start/stop the service in the command line via `net start/stop service` which worked perfectly and I changed my C# program to the following:

```cs
Process p = Process.Start("net", "stop \"" + serviceName + "\"");
p.WaitForExit();
p = Process.Start("net", "start \"" + serviceName + "\"");
p.WaitForExit();
```

Like before, stopping the service worked. The call of `net start service` however ouputted

```
The service is not responding to the control function
more help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186
```

The service is installed for the local logged in user (Administrator) but I don't see why `net start` works from the command line but not out of the code. I also tried the following:

- Set up full permissions for my update program for user `NETWORK SERVICE`
- Started the process with `p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"`
- Changed the `p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` to `Environment.SystemDirectory`
- Changed the `p.MachineName` to `Environment.MachineName`
- Let the thread sleep for 5 seconds after stopping the service

But nothing seemed to make any impact.

Any ideas how to get what I want? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I've seen situations where a service takes a while (e.g. more than a few milliseconds) to `stop`, and a call to `start` will fail. Usually though the error message says this explicitely. Something like "Cannot start service, it is already running." Does your service take a while to stop when done manually from the command line?

Comment: @JesseWebb, I already tried to let the thread sleep manually (added that to the question). In the command line, it usually takes around 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(svr_name);
if (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
    sc.Stop();
    sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
}
```

Put some exception handling to avoid error.

Comment: Stopping the service is not the problem but starting it. However, I tried your suggestion with the start method and it led to the same error `Cannot start service FOVEA Service Debug on computer '.'`

Comment: @Isalomon 
`Cannot start service FOVEA Service Debug on computer '.'.
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
   at ServerMaintenance.ServerMaintenance.DropboxCopy(Dictionary'2 theArgs) in C:\Users\mmueller\...\ServerMaintenance\ServerMaintenance.cs:line 120
   at ServerMaintenance.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\mmueller\...\ServerMaintenance\Program.cs:line 54`

Comment: Investigate events (Event Viewer) at server for finding any issue.

Comment: @Isalomon The Event Viewer outputs that the service has been stopped successfully.. nothing about the restart. I suspect it is a problem of missing rights but I have no more clue what to do now :(